# CTRL+C does not work in msys2

Tags: bash, cygwin, msys2

I used Msys1 for many years and was used to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for killing processes that I start within my shell.

After updating from Msys1 to Msys2 <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> does not work any more.
For example: I start "make" press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Shell prompts to finished and enables typing more commands, but make.exe is still running+working.

**Result of my analysis**:
In Msys1: shell.exe(12345) starts make.exe(23456) and make.exe(23456) has the information, that its parent is (12345).
In Msys2: shell.exe(12345) starts make.exe(23456) and make.exe(23456) has the information, that its parent is the (34567), which is not alive anymore. So I guess Msys2 uses an additional process for starting subprocesses.

I tried bash.exe, shell.exe, mintty.exe,... all seems to have the same problems.

**Content I found searching**
:
This ticket just focuses on missing signal types -> I don't care about that.
https://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/tickets/135/

The issue in this mailing list seems to be near my problem, but I do not understand what I should change, or if the change can only be made within the msys2 implementation. (What is CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP? and how to change it):
https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-08/msg00062.html

Kindest regards
Luke

Comment: `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` and the flag `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` are part of the Win32 API - the answers to the link you show are discussing the source code of Cygwin - you can't alter these without changing the source code.

Comment: Thanks. So this can be ignored. I run a Windows7 64-Bit system

Comment: The Windows API is still called "Win32" even on 64-bit systems.  Its historical, there is no "Win64".  It was to distinguish it from the old 16-bit systems.

Comment: Similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34292325/c-makefile-build-cannot-be-canceled-using-windows-7-eclipse-cdt-mingw-and-ms

Comment: developers from git-windows trying to work around that issue [link](https://github.com/git-for-windows/msys2-runtime/pull/6/commits/c4ba4e3357ff51ecc067115b73ee4b2ebcea482e)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like [mintty](https://mintty.github.io/) provides the default **terminal** for MSYS2 (note that this is different from the shell that is run within). If so, then the "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> kills native (e.g. MSYS2 compiled) programs abruptly rather than sending a catchable signal" problem is the same one as described over on https://superuser.com/questions/606201/how-to-politely-kill-windows-process-from-cygwin and the [MSYS2 wiki porting FAQ](https://github.com/msys2/msys2/wiki/Porting#signals-in-mintty).

If what you're attempting works when you are using Windows' default *terminal* (e.g. when using `cmd.exe` from the start menu) then this is the issue you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

It is in fact suggested in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43406231/2995591) but you can just run each program by winpty.exe which will make CTRL-C working again.